# Embed video and play on android

Tags: android, html5-video

I embed a mp4 video into a webpage, using the embed src script.
I can view it when I browse from iphone, but not android.

I did some research and found out that I need to use html 5, which uses the  tag.

However, how do I find out what version of the video I have? I tried

```
<video width="560" height="340" controls>
  <source src="<?php echo $video; ?>" type='video/mp4; codecs="avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2"'>
</video>
```

But it's not working either. 
Any ideas? Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2):

```
<video id="video" autobuffer height="240" width="360" controls  onclick="this.play();">
<source src="<?php echo $video; ?>">
</video>
```

video must be encoded properly for the device

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. I tried your suggestion, but it didn't work. (I am viewing it through website now) Am I able to see if it works on the web, then it should work on mobile phone ? Anyway to debug or how do I check what am I missing? Thanks again :)

Comment: The video url is auto generated from database, and encode by someone else from another company.

Comment: Hello, the videos are all in mp4 format, but I still can't play the video. Any help? Thanks :)

Comment: If you could provide us with a link, we could tell you pretty quickly if it's a video or a code issue, because I've used the method Aaron described above in the past and it's worked flawlessly for me.

Comment: Hi all, thanks for all the comment. I'm sorry can't post the link coz it's work in development and client doesn't allow it to be view by public yet. :(

Comment: However, I tried with many different mp4 videos and others work, except for that one particular video. We are trying to convert the video to some other format and see how it goes. Thanks all!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a slight variation on a theme: If you're only serving up an MP4 for mobile devices, you can roll the source tag right into the video tag, like so:

```
<video src="<?php echo $video; ?>" id="video" width="360" height="240" type="video/mp4" controls autobuffer onclick="this.play();"></video>
```

Support for the video tag also greatly depends on what version of Android you're running. You definitely need version 2.0 or higher and some older phones like the Nexus One stutter on playback of some higher bitrate videos.

Comment: Hi Andrew, thanks so much for your answer, I will give your solution a try as well. It definitely helps!

Answer (score 0):

I know some devices choke when you specify codecs...some actually are really anal about following that rule. Something to consider is the JW Player. The latest release just dealt with android.

Answer (score 0):

I have been trying to get  .mp4 to work on an android phone, kindle fire and iphone all day. after looking at many websites such as this I found the answer by pure luck and the relentless try try again.

upload your video files to you network first.

go back into the html editor and put the full web address as the source, not just the location from the html current position.

Example:

video controls="controls" autohide="autohide" autoplay="autoplay" loop="loop" poster="wait.jpg" width="900" height="400"

source src="http://www.website.com/cust/flash/bf1/sc2/sc2.mp4" type="video/mp4"

/video

in older device browsers some features like loop and auto play don't work but the video will appear and play. This worked for me.

hope this is helpfull