# Advice for mobile website video embedding for Android devices

Tags: android, video, mobile-website

For my question, time is more important than perfection. I need any advice you can quickly give me about embedding a video in a mobile website which is targeted for Android devices. Since I have only very little time for research (for the first research, only today, but of course the implementation will follow later), I need any advice you can give to me, no matter how vague or imperfect it may be.

Here is the scenario:

- A video must be embedded in a mobile website, using HTML.
- Only Android clients are relevant, because iPhones and non-Android devices will be directed to another URL.
- Preferably, the video should be integrated into the rest of the web page. In case an external player needs to be opened, it would be preferable if that player has a "return to web page" button of some kind that will return the user to the web page.
- The customer is aware that this will not work perfectly on all devices, but we want to find a solution that works well at least on the more modern devices.

If you have any experience regarding this field, please let me know of it. Here are some areas that might be helpful:

- HTML code that you have found to be working
- Encoding specifics regarding the video (e.g. which codecs to use or not to use)
- Other StackOverflow questions regarding this topic which I have overseen in my haste (sorry about that, time is sparse for me right now)

Since I can only choose one of the replies to be *the* answer, my choice for that has to be very arbitrary.

So far, I have found these two other StackOverflow questions, which cover parts of this topic:

- [What video format will play on all Android devices?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5097101/what-video-format-will-play-on-all-android-devices)
- [Embed video and play on android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4057057/embed-video-and-play-on-android)

Answer (score 1):

What about embedding flash? Not all android devices have it but the ones have it should be able to play properly encoded mp4 video

For video encoding check http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html

Comment: Thanks! I forgot to mention that the development of an Android-capable Flash app would be out of scope for the project.